# Add track points in layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shape file and I want to add a layer which includes the track points (x coordinate , Y - coordinate for the attribute table). I need the tracks for identifying the buidlings and for calculations.

[image]

This is what it looks like.

And the following picture shows what I need, the red dots are the track points. I got them from OSM by adding tracks and track points out of a GPX. The other file wasn't a GPX and I couldn't select adding track points as I added this layer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use Extract vertices tool to get the corner points of the polygon shapefile, then use Add geometry attributes to add the x and y coordinates of the corner points.

Extract vertices tool is located in `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Extract vertices tool`. Add Add geometry attributes tool is located from `Vector main menu -> Geometry tools -> Add geometry attributes`.

Please note that using extract vertices tool you will get 5 vertices for each polygon, the first and fifth vertices are same in order to close the polygon shapefile. If you want to remove the duplicate points, you need to use Remove duplicate vertices tool from `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Remove duplicate vertices`

Comment: I didn't find the extract vertices tool but that could be  because of the different language. Or is there a plug in necessary for this tool?

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.4.5. You may find the tool from vector main menu->Geometry tools. I am currently not in office, but as far as I remember you can also find the tool there.